# Why can't I install MacTeX or BasicTeX on my Mac?

Tags: installing, mactex

I am a beginner for LaTeX and I was trying to install the package BasicTeX on my mac (version 10.7.3). Everything went well - downloading the `.zip` file from TUG, unarchiving--until I actually started to install the package.

[image: Here is what I got at the last stage of the installation. Everything working fine up till now.]

But then

[image: Here is the error.]

I also tried MacTeX but it also failed. Here is the installer log for the full MacTex:

```
**Apr 11 20:39:04 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7796]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----**

**Apr 11 20:43:07 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7796]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Ghostscript-9.02.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7fd45e807e90 {NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/Ghostscript-9.02.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.tug.mactex.ghostscript9.02, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Ghostscript-9.02.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postflight";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cGhostscript-9.02.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/Ghostscript-9.02.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.tug.mactex.ghostscript9.02";
    }**

**Apr 11 20:43:08 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7783]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.**

**Apr 11 20:43:08 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7783]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.**


**Apr 11 20:43:08 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7783]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.**
```

I tried deselecting the Ghostscript package but a similar problem occurred with "GUI Application", here is the full log:

```
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-686.3
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-530
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Hardware: MacBookPro8,1 @ 2.70 GHz (x 4), 4096 MB RAM
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/r2/gx0svmcs5h95bd34kkrvzknr0000gn/T/
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: HOME=/Users/William
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: USER=William
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: LOGNAME=William
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-NlNQAn/org.x:0
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-mwoggh/Listeners
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-wNPeC9/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-ZINUEC/Render
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: MacTeX-2011  Installation Log
Apr 11 21:06:12 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Opened from: /Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg
Apr 11 21:07:03 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
Apr 11 21:08:18 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFPKGDerivedDocument sortedPackageLocations]: result = (
    "file://localhost"
)
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro runner[7847]: Administrator authorization granted.
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: ================================================================================
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: User picked Custom Install
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Choices selected for installation:
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:   Install: "MacTeX-2011"
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:       MacTeX-2011.mpkg : org.tug.mactex.mactex2011 : 1.3.0.1.3
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:   Install: "GUI Applications"
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:       GUI-Applications.pkg : org.tug.mactex.gui : 1.3.0.1.3
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:   Install: "ImageMagick Convert 6.6.9-3"
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:       ImageMagick-Convert-6.6.9-3.pkg : org.tug.mactex.imagemagick-convert-6.6.9-3 : 1.3.0.1.3
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:   Install: "Latin Modern Fonts"
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:       Latin-Modern-Fonts.pkg : org.tug.mactex.latin-modern : 1.3.0.1.3
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:   Install: "TeX Live 2011"
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]:       TeXLive-2011.pkg : org.tug.mactex.texlive2011 : 1.3.0.1.3
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: ================================================================================
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Apr 11 21:08:25 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFPKGDerivedDocument sortedPackageLocations]: result = (
    "file://localhost"
)
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: location = file://localhost
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/ImageMagick-Convert-6.6.9-3.pkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/Latin-Modern-Fonts.pkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/TeXLive-2011.pkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Set authorization level to root for session
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Will use PK session
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Starting installation:
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 433.11 GB (433109905408 bytes).
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/r2/gx0svmcs5h95bd34kkrvzknr0000gn/T//Install.7837eNj0ED"
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: IFPKInstallElement (6 packages)
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <6 packages, destination=/>
Apr 11 21:08:26 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: packages=(
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg>",
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg>",
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/ImageMagick-Convert-6.6.9-3.pkg>",
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/Latin-Modern-Fonts.pkg>",
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/TeXLive-2011.pkg>",
    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg>"
)
Apr 11 21:08:27 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root, uid=0)
Apr 11 21:08:38 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/ImageMagick-Convert-6.6.9-3.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root, uid=0)
Apr 11 21:08:39 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/Latin-Modern-Fonts.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root, uid=0)
Apr 11 21:08:39 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/TeXLive-2011.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root, uid=0)
Apr 11 21:10:52 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root (3 items) to /
Apr 11 21:12:19 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg/Contents/Resources
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro installd[7850]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “GUI-Applications.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7ffb9d7e09f0 {NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.tug.mactex.gui, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “GUI-Applications.pkg”.} {
    NSFilePath = "./postflight";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cGUI-Applications.pkg\U201d.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg";
    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.tug.mactex.gui";
}
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “GUI-Applications.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f9de9616730 {NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/William/Downloads/MacTeX-2011.mpkg/Contents/Packages/GUI-Applications.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.tug.mactex.gui, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “GUI-Applications.pkg”.}
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: IFDInstallController E9535990 state = 7
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Apr 11 21:12:22 William-Lius-MacBook-Pro Installer[7837]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

I tried repairing permission for the harddrive but the same problems persists. And even if I select only "TeX Live" when installing full MacTex, it still fails.

Can anybody help explain what's going on here? It's kind of frustrating to get stuck at this stage. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to try the full MacTeX. You can see more about the error by looking at the installation log that's accessible from the Installer application menu.

Comment: @egreg I tried MacTex again but it still doesn't work out. I have updated the installer log in my question.

Comment: The message tells about Ghostscript 9.02 (which is quite strange). In the early stages of the installation you can customize it: try unselecting Ghostscript. You might also get more info about the error if you choose the maximum logging level (shortcut: Command-L Command-3).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the advice! I tried deselecting Ghostscript. I don't know what's wrong with my Mac but a new problem popped up... Is it advisable if I just install Tex Live alone?

Comment: I suspect a permission problem. Run Disk Utility; choose the "Macintosh HD" volume and do "Repair Disk Permissions".

Comment: just two thoughts: 1. check whether your Download is complete (mactex is a quite large package did you use this source http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/ ?) 2. recently there was a update to the installer (by apple) did you install this update already?

Comment: You can try to download the torrent file of MacTeX 2011

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone on the Ars Technica forums realized what was wrong. I will bet quite a bit of money that you used The Unarchiver to unzip the file that contained the `.mpkg` file. Apparently, something about the way it unzips introduced some sort of corruption. If you go back, and instead of using The Unarchiver, use Apple's own Archive Utility, then try the installation using that newly unzipped `.mpkg`, it should work. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Have you downloaded from bittorrent? There is support for MacTeX Here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/support/emailform/. As a last option, have you tried to install it from the command line (see comment above)?

Comment: Thanks @Alan, your suggestion worked!!! And yes I did use the Unarchiver to unzip the file, so I think the problem is indeed with the Unarchiver. Many thanks again! I almost got desperate and gave up on this.

Comment: I just want to confirm that I had the same problem as Vokram, and the solution suggested by Joseph and Adam worked fine! It seems to be a problem with the Unarchiver.

Comment: I tried the unarchiver and it says that payload and another file are corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the Ghostcript package. I don't know if this is possible, but you could deselect that package in Installation Type (probably you won't need Ghostscript). Otherwise, you can install Texlive from the internet (command line from terminal) and then install an editor.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! However I tried deselecting Ghostscript but a new problem with "GUI applications" popped up (I updated the log). Do you have any idea what might be causing all this mess with my Mac? Is it okay to install Tex Live all along?

Comment: I see you tried egreg’s solution first, and tried selecting only TexLive for install. I would check again if your download is correct... As a last recourse, you can try one of the following: a) download the MacTeX 2011 torrent, as mimmo said, (which will hopefully be error-free); or b) install using the command line, which will download everything and install directly (http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I have installed MacTex several times on a couple of machines (Lion and Snow Leopard) and never encountered any problem.

Comment: Joseph, I tried again but it still doesn't work, so I guess there must be something really wrong with my Mac. I think I'll just restore my laptop sometime later. But still, thanks for your help all along!

Comment: @Vokram, You mean, it didn’t install from the command line?

Comment: Yes Joseph, it didn't work even from the command line. But I guess this is the same problem from the Unarchiver thing. I tried Alan's method and the installation is successful. Problem finally solved now. Thank you for your suggestions again!

Comment: @Vokram, glad to see your problem solved, but when I said “from the command line”, the netinstall for Texlive (not MacTex) does not download any .zip files, it installs them *from the net*. Another option is that Safari automatically unzips every zip file it downloads (and uses the native MAC Archive Utility, not the Unarchiver), so that would prevent problems with other zip files as well.